# Why CMake fail to recognise a library despite that it has been added by 'include_directories'?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management

My CMakeList file defined a list of directory that should be included in the build path:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(lib)
include_directories(lib/freeglut)
include_directories(lib/freeglut/include)
include_directories(lib/freeglut/include/GL)
include_directories(lib/matrix)
include_directories(lib/mavlink)
include_directories(lib/mavlink/common)
include_directories(src)
include_directories(src/Drawing)
include_directories(src/Math)
include_directories(src/MavlinkNode)
include_directories(src/Simulation)
include_directories(src/Utility)
...
```

all dependent files are under /lib. When I run `CMake CMakeList.txt & make`, I got the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable FCND_Controls_CPP
CMakeFiles/FCND_Controls_CPP.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/peng/git-drone/__Udacity__/FCND-Controls-CPP/src/main.cpp:68: undefined reference to `glutTimerFunc'
/home/peng/git-drone/__Udacity__/FCND-Controls-CPP/src/main.cpp:70: undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
...
```

While both functions glutTimerFunc and glutMainLoop are under 'lib/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut.h'. Yet either CMake and make is ignoring them. Why this could happen and what should I do to fix them?

I'm using cmake 3.9.1, I've tried 2 backends: gcc/g++ and clang/clang++ and both gave the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Tsyvarev This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Samaursa: Why not duplicate? The question's author got "undefined reference" and he doesn't know what does it mean. He expects functions to be defined in the header file, and doesn't note word "linking". The duplicate question explains the meaning of "undefined reference" and get hints what to do with that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev True, OP seems to not know what _underfined reference_ means, however since he is using `CMake`, they cannot exactly follow the solution of the other question. The other question/solution is a good reference for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `include_directories` which are directories for the compiler to check for includes. What you should be using is `target_link_libraries`.

However, since you are using a known library, you'll want to do something like this (you can find this information in the `FindGLUT.cmake` file under the `cmake-modules` directory):

```
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(your_exe PUBLIC ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}) # could also be PRIVATE, depending on usage
target_link_libraries(your_exe ${GLUT_LIBRARY} )
```

Note that you'll also need to do the same with `OpenGL` libraries with the cached variables `${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}` and `${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}`.

> Note: Try to avoid using `include_directories` (without target) as that is considered the *older* style and has the drawback of pollutating the include directories of all targets.

Comment: Looks like not the case: After I change the first few include_directories into target_link_libraries I got this error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "lib" which is not built by this
  project.

Comment: You cannot replace `include_directories` with `target_link_libraries`. You can replace `include_directories` with `target_include_directories` in which case you also have to use `PUBLIC` (I forgot to put that in my solution, see edit to my answer).